# how to add deeplink with url like "https://www.appname.com/profile" for ios in react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, url, deep-linking

In a project I need to implement deeplinking with url with "https://www.appname.com/profile". so, I can open webpage if app is not installed in phone. I have added  `<data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.appName.com"/>` in android manifest and it is working for android but I also need for iOS. I have tried with changing url Schemas to "https://www.appname.com" but it is not working. So can anyone help me with the issue for iOS.

Comment: Custom url schemes do not support http, instead use universal links: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app.